# loop through subArray as $key => $value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, iteration

given this **data structure**:

```
    array(2) {
    [0] array(7) {
        ["model_id"] 218
        ["total"] 10
        ["brand"] "This Brand"
        ["model_name"] "This Name"
        ["picture"] "this pic.jpg"
        ["color"] "Black"
        ["sizes"] array(3) {
            ["4"] "10 %"
            ["5"] "80 %"
            ["6"] "10 %"
        }
    }
    [1] array(7) {
        ["model_id"] 219
        ["total"] 10
        ["brand"] "This Brand"
        ["model_name"] "ThatName"
        ["picture"] "that pic.jpg"
        ["color"] "Black"
        ["sizes"] array(3) {
            ["4"] "20 %"
            ["5"] "50 %"
            ["6"] "30 %"
        }
    }
}
```

How can you loop into **sizes** as `$key => $value` ?

What I tried didn't work so far, like nested loops.

```
foreach($array as $i){

            foreach($i as $z){

                foreach($z as $key => $value){

                    print_r($key);

                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

results in **error**: **`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`**

Comment: Your data structure is JSON, not a PHP array. Are you aware of that? The thing you are looking for is recursive calls to a function: the function calls itself whenever it wants to go a level deeper inside the array.

Comment: its looks like json data first you have to decode this value by json_decode function.

Comment: change `foreach($i as $z)` to `foreach($i['size'] as $kye => $value)` and remove next foreach. I think you have one extra foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $i){
    foreach($i['sizes'] as $key => $value){
        echo $key.'->'.$value;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayas = json_decode($array);
foreach($arrayas $i){

        foreach($i as $z){

            foreach($z as $key => $value){

                print_r($key);

            }  
        }
    }
}
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$decarray = json_decode($array);

foreach($decarray as $keyDec => $valArr ){
    foreach($valArr as $keyOuter => $valOuter){
        if($keyOuter == "sizes"){
            foreach($valOuter as $keyInner => $valInner){
                echo $keyInner.":".$valInner ''
            }  
        }
    }
}
```