# Confused about how to loop through subArray

Tags: php, arrays

First of all I have searched for the similar threads  on  StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353541/loop-through-subarray-as-key-value-in-php)

```
$myvar = array ("key_name" => array("tom", "an", "bob"),
     "key_age" => array("1", "10", "12")
    );
```

I have tried lot of things but  I couldn't

```
foreach($myvar as $i){
    foreach ($i as $key => $value) {
        echo print_r($i);
    }
```

Comment: Whats the question? Whats the expected output?

Comment: hi ..I am trying to get "key_name" and loop through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get "key_name" and loop through it

```
<?php
$myvar = array (
    "key_name" => array("tom", "an", "bob"),
    "key_age" => array("1", "10", "12")
);

foreach ($myvar['key_name'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

**Result:**

```
tomanbob
```

https://3v4l.org/tEFvS

If you want to loop through both:

```
foreach ($myvar as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
tomanbob11012
```

https://3v4l.org/cMFUh

Check out, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for info on using foreach

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walker](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). So you can do something like this :

```
array_walk($myvar,function($sub_items,$key){
echo "Key is >> " . $key . "\n";
foreach($sub_items as $item){
    echo $item . "\n";
}

echo "------------ \n ";
```

});

Note:
I put an echo with a new line to understand how to implement that!

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know